# Where is QuartzJobBean located in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to learn about Quartz in Spring from this article :
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-3-scheduler-example-jdk-timer-and-quartz-showcase/

when I imported this example in STS I got an error :

> The import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz cannot be 
>    resolved

in this line :

> import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very match, is there anyway how to find this error ? I just want to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is tutorial quite detail about quarzt job. you can reference from it
http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/

Comment: Thanks, I went to that site too.